# Convertion JSON TO Datatable gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm receiving following JSON object from my server

```
"[{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"National Savings Bank \",\"Bank_Name\":\"National Savings Bank \",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"NDB Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"NDB Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Peoples Merchant Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Peoples Merchant Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"DFCC Vardhana Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"DFCC Vardhana Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Mercantile Merchant Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Mercantile Merchant Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Union Commercial Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Union Commercial Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Deutsche Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Deutsche Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Hatton National Bank PLC\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Hatton National Bank PLC\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Seylan Merchant Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Seylan Merchant Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Nations Trust Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Nations Trust Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"HSBC\",\"Bank_Name\":\"HSBC\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Standard Chartered Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Standard Chartered Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"State Bank of India\",\"Bank_Name\":\"State Bank of India\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Central Bank of Sri Lanka\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Central Bank of Sri Lanka\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Peoples Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Peoples Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Pan Asia Banking Corporation PLC\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Pan Asia Banking Corporation PLC\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Central Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Central Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Commercial Bank of Ceylon\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Commercial Bank of Ceylon\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Amana Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Amana Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Other\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Other\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Bank of Ceylon\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Bank of Ceylon\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"ICICI Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"ICICI Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Foreign Banks\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Foreign Banks\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"MBSL Savings Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"MBSL Savings Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Citibank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Citibank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Sampath Bank PLC\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Sampath Bank PLC\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Merchant Bank of Sri Lanka\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Merchant Bank of Sri Lanka\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"DFCC Bank\",\"Bank_Name\":\"DFCC Bank\",\"Status\":0},{\"Sync_Time\":\"\\/Date(1447935488033)\\/\",\"Bank_Code\":\"Seylan Bank PLC\",\"Bank_Name\":\"Seylan Bank PLC\",\"Status\":0}]"
```

I'm using following method to convert it into C# DataTable

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd() ;
    var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(result); 
}
```

but it gives following error;

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException'
>   occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable.
>   Expected StartArray, got String. Path '', line 1, position 3784.

could someone please explain the reason?

Comment: You'll have to convert it to an object that matches the structure of the json - then you could map to a datatable if that is actually what you need

Comment: Also, you might want to format the json so it is more readable in thw question

Answer (score 0):

First, create a class with your object structure:

```
  [JsonObject]
  public class BankData
  {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Sync_Time")]
    public string Sync_Time { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Bank_Code")]
    public string Bank_Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Bank_Name")]
    public string Bank_Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }
  }
```

Then create a method to parse your json and convert it to array:

```
  var jsonResponse = .....get json from server...
  var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BankData[]>(jsonResponse);
  // res is your array of BankData.... you can use it here...
```